# How to package and include fragment jars in build jar using maven?

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, maven-plugin, rcp, target-platform

I have translated the help window in our RCP app using babel fragment jars(doesn't have poms). I had to include the fragments in target platform and load them in plugins for run configurations. This way it worked in eclipse workspace.

Now, when maven clean build is done, they are not packaged in the target plugin

I tried to mavenise those fragment jars and installed them in local m2 repo and added them in product pom dependencies then also they are not pulled.

When, I paste those jars in target plugin manually & added them in config.ini they work.

Anyone can help how to get these fragment jars to the target plugin ?

Comment: What maven build? Is this using [tag:tycho]?

Comment: not tycho, but apache and company custom plugins are used to build. I need to know how we can add the extra fragments to the target/plugin ?

Comment: We can't possibly help if we have no idea how your build system works. Tycho is the only supported way to build RCPs

Comment: Can you tell how can I include fragment jars to my main build since they don't have artifact id ? If I have to make OSGI, what I will provide in the embed dependency tags ?